# Mongo Db. Incorrect pipeline query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to join two collection.
First collection:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  ...
}
```

Second collection:

```
{
  _id: '2',
  substitutions: [
    { masterProductId: '1', ... }
  ],
}
```

If I join them via usual lookup, everything is ok. I get valuable result.

```
'$lookup': {
      'from': 'secondCollection', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': 'substitutions.masterProductId', 
      'as': 'secondCollection'
    }
```

But! When I try to use pipeline, I have response with empty 'secondCollection'.

```
'$lookup': {
      'from': 'secondCollection', 
      'let': { 
        'foreignId': '$substitutions.masterProductId'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$eq': [
                '$_id', '$$foreignId'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'secondCollection'
    }
  }
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

In your `let` clause, you are trying to reference the field `substitutions.masterProductId` in collection 2. However, you can only refer to field in collection 1 in the `let` clause.

So for your case, the correct way for `$lookup` should be :

```js
{
'$lookup': {
      'from': 'secondCollection', 
      'let': { 
        'id': '$_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$in': [
                '$$id', '$substitutions.masterProductId'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'secondCollection'
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the [official MongoDB document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-let) about the `let` clause for your reference.

Comment: Should be `$in` not `$eq` as `$substitutions.masterProductId` returns an array.

Comment: Thanks @YongShun for pointing out the mistake! Corrected accordingly :)